# SSIS : Conversion DT_NTEXT to DT_WSTR

Tags: ssis

Whats the best way to convert DT_NTEXT to DT_WSTR in Derived Colum Transformation.

Regards

Comment: what is the length of NTEXT column?

Comment: If length is <=255 you can (DT_WSTR,255)DT_NTEXT Column

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is that the max length of `DT_NTEXT` is `2^30 ~ 1.073` billion characters, while `DT_WSTR` max length is 4000 characters.

If all your fields are less than 4000, try **Data Conversion Transformation** and it may only raise a warning at design time. You would add this before of after the **Derived Column Transformation**.

Comment: To solve my problem, I needed to have a template for excel that had 1000 characters in a field I needed to allow for more than 255 characters but this pointed me in the right direction.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two solution for any types of data conversion in **SSIS Package**

1. Use below link

   [SQL Server and SSIS Data Types](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-and-ssis-data-types/)
2. Mmanually convert that into Unicode string.

   **(DT_WSTR,20)Columnname** expression.